# Plotting line plot with groupby in matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset (abbreviated, but still conveys the same idea). I want to show how user score changes over time (the postDate conveys time). The data is also presorted by `postDate`. The hope is to see a nice plot (perhaps using seaborn if possible) that has the score as the y-axis, time as the x-axis, and shows the users' scores over time (with a separate line for each user). Do I need to convert the `postDate` (currently a string) to another format in order to plot nicely? Thank you so much!

```
userID   postDate                                userScore (1-10 scale)
Mia1     2017-01-11 09:07:10.616328+00:00        8
John2    2017-01-17 08:05:45.917629+00:00        6
Leila1   2017-01-22 07:47:67.615628+00:00        9
Mia1     2017-01-30 03:45:50.817325+00:00        7
Leila    2017-02-02 06:38:01.517223+00:00        10
```

Comment: where does the `groupby` come in? do you want a line for each user?

Comment: Yes, the groupby is a separate line for each user (and there are many users -- some with 20 posts or more). There could also be other ways to do this, I was just thinking a groupby might be necessary.

Comment: it'll be something like: `df.pipe(seaborn.FacetGrid, hue='userID').map(plt.plot, 'postDate', 'userScore')`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data you show your postDate series is already pandas datetime values. So to plot with dates on the X axis the key in matplotlib is to use [plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date), not plot. Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for key, g in df.groupby['userID']:
    ax.plot_date(g['postDate'], g['userScore'], label=key)

ax.legend()
```

Answer (score -2):

I've used [plotly](https://plot.ly/) before, it's a really nice option to do interactive visualizations if you are using Jupyter Notebook. You generate `htmls` or plot inline in Jupyter with cufflinks. It's only paid for hosting your graphs somewhere but I use it for free for my own data analysis.

Install plotly and also cufflinks, cufflinks helps out to do plots almost instantly with pandas dfs.

For example you could do:

```
your_df.iplot(x='postDate', y='userScore')
```

this will automatically give you the 'time-series' you describe.